# Switch dynamically to cookieless session state asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, state-management

We have a requirement in which we need to switch dynamically to cookieless session.The following   msdn link shows that we can enable cookiless sessions by modifying webconfig http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx ,Is there exist any method  to switch dynamically to cookieless session?Any help would be appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: I'm curious. What is your requirement? Why do you need to switch to cookieless on the fly in production ?

Comment: @EoinCampbell Our specific requirement says so, they need to switch to cookieless session on runtime with a button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is.  Typically, you would just check to see if they have cookies enabled by using Session.IsCookieless and if not redirect them to a page informing them that cookies are required.  Check out this link for more info:

[Cookieless Session State Asp.net](http://dotnetfarrukhabbas.blogspot.com/2011/04/cookieless-session-state-aspnet.html)