# Dynamic use of cookies in Forms-Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, session-cookies

Currently I have 2 ways:

1. when i set my web.config `cookieless="UseCookies"` my url looks that:

   http://example.com/Stuff

   `<sessionState timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies"/>`
2. when i set `cookieless="true"` i have such urls

   http://example.com/%28S%28uanyuxwgaviyonky0lxwq3vq%29%29/Stuff

   `<sessionState timeout="60" cookieless="true"/>`

---

Is i possible to set `cookieless` property dynamic? Something like

```
if(/*condition*/)
{
    sessionState .cookieless = "true";
}
else
{
    sessionState .cookieless = "UseCookies";
}
```

This must be somewhere in `SessionStart` of Global.asax or something

Comment: By dynamic you mean per-request or just in code but still global, per application?

Comment: @Evk i want to handle it per Session - i have a website with multiple "start -pages" and i want to decide it depending which page was called first

Comment: You want to set this for FormsAuthentication cookies ?

Comment: In some cases i can't set cookies at all - that's what i need cookieless session

Comment: Per the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433179/switch-dynamically-to-cookieless-session-state-asp-net), as well as from other resources setting up CookieLess or UseCookies dynamically is not possible. But, you can use AutoDetect to know about the browser's support for cookies. Hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: why is there a winforms tag in there?

Answer (score 0):

The basic Idea here is you want to modify the `WebConfig` file at runtime. i didn't tried my-self , but as curiosity i searched over internet , and found [This link](http://www.totaltechnet.com/UpdateConfig/UpdateConfig.htm) 
and according to this your code in `Global.asax` will be like

**Note** : this actually writes the new value the web.config

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            Configuration config;
            config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            SessionStateSection SessionState = config.GetSection("system.web/sessionState") as SessionStateSection;

            if (SessionState != null)
            {
                SessionState.Mode = System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateMode.InProc;// changes 

                if (true/*condition*/)
                {
                    SessionState.Cookieless = System.Web.HttpCookieMode.UseCookies;
                }
                else
                {
                    SessionState.Cookieless = System.Web.HttpCookieMode.UseUri; // not sure about this one
                }
                config.Save();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is discussed regularly since 2003 (see for example [Switch dynamically to cookieless session state asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433179/switch-dynamically-to-cookieless-session-state-asp-net).
You cannot change cookieless false/true from the application because decision is made by IIS before begin_request fired.
Some available options are:
A.

```
<system.web>
   <sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

B.

Set some folder inside your webroot as web application and set cookieless="true"

Comment: I understand that it is not the answer you want but this is what you have to accept. Just go with it.

Answer (score 0):

IIS manage it before application request start so you can not change it on application level.